# mysql 5.7.12 - how to sequentially get the difference of two columns?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with process ids, start times, and end times.

```
pid start               end
1   2020-01-01 01:00:00 2020-01-01 02:00:00
1   2020-01-02 01:00:00 2020-01-02 01:30:00
1   2020-01-03 01:00:00 2020-01-03 01:10:00
```

I need to do some analysis on this so I need the last 5 run times in the format

```
pid t1 t2 t3 t4 t5
1   10 30 60
```

I can get the latest run time by subtracting max value of start and end time stamps but how do I get the rest?

Comment: What is the primary key in your table?

Comment: @MichalJ.Figurski this table doesn't have one it's a log table. however I am joining this with another table where pid is the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses window functions (available in MySQL 8.0) and date arithmetics:

```
select pid,
    max(case when rn = 1 then timestampdiff(minute, startts, endts) end) t1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then timestampdiff(minute, startts, endts) end) t2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then timestampdiff(minute, startts, endts) end) t3,
    max(case when rn = 4 then timestampdiff(minute, startts, endts) end) t4,
    max(case when rn = 5 then timestampdiff(minute, startts, endts) end) t5 
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by pid order startts desc, endts desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 5
group by pid
```

Notes:

- `start` and `end` are language keywords; I renamed the columns to `startts` and `endts` in the query
- this defines the last 5 runs as the runs with the greatest `startts` and `endts`
- this puts the latest run in the first column, which is slightly different than your expected result, but makes more sense to me

Comment: there is a syntax error: missing 'closing parenthesis' on over

Comment: @hitodo9051: which version of MySQL are you running? `select version()` can tell you.